# Skeletal animation: distorted mesh for fbx file but not dae file?

Tags: opengl, graphics, assimp

I am having a very weird trouble using Assimp to load and do skeletal animation. I am using two models to test my code, and both models are loaded correctly with Assimp Viewer so there should be no errors with them themselves. However, when I load these two models with my code, only 1 works correctly.

[image]

Obviously, this one does not work. The animation of the neck of the chicken works as expected, but the legs are distorted.

[image]

This one works perfectly.

The only differences I can think of are that the first model is an fbx file while the second is a dae file and that the first one has multiple meshes, which requires me to transform them back to the same root space if I want the static model to load correctly, while the second one only has one mesh that is already at origin in root space. The meshes I have to transform back to the same space, unsurprisingly, are those that contains legs of the chicken.

I am actually not using Assimp's mOffsetMatrix but calculating my own inverseBindTransform. I assume I calculate them correctly because 1 of my models works. Below is an overview of my matrix multiplication:

```
modelView * toWorldMatrix * desiredPoseMatrix * inverseBindTransform * meshToWorldMat * position
```

meshToWorldMat is the transform that brings mesh space back to world space. (toWorldMatrix * desiredPoseMatrix) is just the result of the keyframe interpolation multiplied with its parentMatrix.

What is wrong with my approach?

Update: I also discover that some meshes of the distorted fbx model share the same bone, though I'm not sure if this is significant.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following transformation for each bone in skeleton:

```
math::Matrix4F Bone::getTransform(const NodePtr& meshNode) const
{
    math::Matrix4F fullCurrentMesh = meshNode->getWorldTransformation()
                                   * meshNode->getLocalInitTransformation(ETransformation::Geometry);

    math::Matrix4F fullInitMesh = meshNode->getWorldInitTransformation()
                                * meshNode->getLocalInitTransformation(ETransformation::Geometry);

    math::Matrix4F relPose0 = (m_node->getWorldInitTransformation() * m_bindPoseBone).getInverse()
                            * fullInitMesh;

    math::Matrix4F relPoseInv = fullCurrentMesh.getInverse() * m_node->getWorldTransformation();

    return relPoseInv * relPose0;
}
```

All "init" matrices are calculated in timestamp = 0, "local" matrices are data from "fbx" file, m_bindPoseBone is bind pose for this bone (also from "fbx")

Comment: Im sorry but I have trouble following your logic. Can you clarify exactly what matrix you are using and their purpose?